# Best way to manipulate sqlalchemy object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working with sqlalchemy and would like to loop through a set of rows from a table add a couple of calculated rows and insert them into a second table. I could convert the row object to a dictionary and use that:

```
def object_as_dict(obj):
    return {c.key: getattr(obj, c.key)
            for c in inspect(obj).mapper.column_attrs}

for row in session.query(source).limit(50):

    d = object_as_dict(row)
    del d['id'] # DON'T FORGET TO REMOVE ID FROM FIRST TABLE FROM DICT
    item = Filtered_Item()
    for k in d.keys():
        item[k] = d.get(k)

    item['calc1']=None
    item['calc2'] = None
```

But I'm wondering if there is a more direct way to work with a sqlalchemy row object?

Comment: ah, maybe I misunderstood, you're asking how to do this WITHOUT using a dictionary?

Comment: is the answer what you're looking for or not really?

Comment: This  is very helpful. I will need to digest this but Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this without serializing, you might try this:

```
for row in session.query(source).limit(50):
  session.add(models.MyOtherModel(val=foo(row.val),val2=bar(row.bal2))
```

Personally I don't think there is anything wrong with serializing/deserializing the data.  I do about 25 million writes a day using a similar technique to this:

```
def serialze_sqlalchemy_data(model, items):
    headers = sqlalchemy_headers(model)

    for record in items:
        row = {str(k): str(v) for k, v in
           zip(headers, [getattr(record, header.lower(), str(header.lower())) for header in headers])}
        yield row

def sqlalchemy_headers(model):
    try:
        _headers = [col.name for col in model.__mapper__.columns]
    except AttributeError:
        _headers = [col for col in model.__dict__.keys()
                    if isinstance(model.__dict__[col], InstrumentedAttribute)]
    return _headers
```

You could then do something like:

```
def foo(row):
  row['val'] = 'taco'
  row['val2'] = 42
  return row

mymodel = models.MyModel
rows = session.query(mymodel)
rowdata = serialize_sqlalchemy_data(mymodel, rows)

table2 = models.MyModel2
session.bulk_insert_mappings(tables2, map(foo, rowdata))
session.commit()
session.close()
```